# How to setup routing in pancakeswap

Tags: pancakeswap, amm

Pancake V2 has this smart order routing(SOR) feature. I was wondering how to build this efficiently, so that I can do permutation and combinations on existing pairs and get their reserves, and thereby calculate best output from them.